# Unable to install Tensorflow 2.15 and some dependencies

Tags: installation, anaconda3, tensorflow2

I wanted to install tensorflow in a PC which is not connected to internet. I downloaded tensorflow from an online PC using  `pip download tensorflow -d /path/to/download/directory` . I got tensorflow-2.15.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl and associated dependencies.

Then I transferred these to the offline PC (Windows 10 without GPU). This PC has Anaconda3 2023.9 version already installed in it. Then tried to install using `pip install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/download/directory tensorflow`. This gave errors as given below.

"Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from version: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

I tried to install keras (keras-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl). No issues were faced. Further I tried with all the downloaded dependencies. Except grpcio-1.62.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, ml_dtypes-0.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, protobuf-4.25.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, tensorflow_intel-2.15.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, tensorflow-2.15.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.31.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, I could install everything else.

Any help regarding installation of tensorflow in my offline PC will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please see: [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow 2.15 installation is little crazier than usual.
The dependencies works for online version are:

```
--extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com
tensorrt-bindings==8.6.1
tensorrt-libs==8.6.1  
tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.15.0
```

It needs `[and-cuda]` to be able to properly install it.

Since you are doing offline, then `tensorrt-bindings` and `tersorrt-libs` should be taken care too.

Also, you do need to install keras separately, when installing tf.